# Send data from java program to google earth for realtime display

Tags: java, google-maps, kml, google-api-java-client, google-earth-plugin

I have a java program and I want to display its result **in realtime** as features on google earth. I tried with kml but I don't think it is the solution.
I found in google developpers website that there is a google earth engine API but it comes with a web-based IDE so my question is, how an I link it with my Java program?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "send data to google earth"?

Comment: I want to plot placemark with ballons, timestamp, ... and polygons.

Comment: I mean, I have a java program that simulate a virtual city and I want to show data like area where the are lot of people (represented by a polygon for example) in google earth. I have the coordinates needed and the timestamp but I don't know how to display it in realtime in Google earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in JavaFX by using WebView and implement Google Map on it.
Take a look at this site: [GMapsFX :: Add Google Maps to your JavaFX application.](https://rterp.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/gmapsfx-add-google-maps-to-your-javafx-application/)

Comment: I've used this method and it works great.  HOWEVER....the Google Earth plugin is going to be retired on December 12th, 2015.  If longevity is important to you, you might want to look into other map solutions.

Comment: @AdamFinley You're right, I ll check an other map solution
I'll check if openlayers can provide me what I need, thank you

Answer (score 0):

hmmm... I am using another solution now and hope this help :

( may refer to https://sites.google.com/site/canadadennischen888/home/kml/auto-refresh-3d-tracking )(plus, in my other page, there is sample java code)

Details as :

1. prepare a RestFul service to generate KML file from DB (KML sample as inside above link)
2. My other jsp code will generate a KMZ file which has a link to my Restful service. KMZ file has onInterval ( as in the bottom)
3. Jsp web page allow user to download KMZ file.
4. When Google Earth open KMZ file, Google Earth will auto refresh to get new data from that Restful service
5. Everytime refreshing, server will send the latest update KML data with new data to GE.

KMZ sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
 xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <NetworkLink> 
 <name>Dennis_Chen_Canada@Hotmail.com</name> 
 <open>1</open> 
 <Link> 
 <href>http://localhost:9080/google-earth-project/rest/kml/10001/20002</href> 
 <refreshMode>onInterval</refreshMode> 
 </Link>
 </NetworkLink>
 </kml>
```

result as :

[image]